# Data safety in Scriptable Object based architecture

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

**Immediately I would like to say that if a similar question has been asked before, please point me to it.**

Let's say I have a Scriptable Object that I use to pass a player's health from one system to another.

```
public class HealthSO: ScriptableObject {
   [ReadOnly]
   public float health;
}
```

A class called `PlayerHealth` sets the value in the Scriptable Object so that other systems can use it. E.g: the player's health bar.

It's great because I can freely connect different systems without referencing them, but it is not without its problems, and there is one that concerns me the most.

How do I make sure that the only class that can change the health value in the Scriptable Object is `PlayerHealth`?

Or maybe it is something that I shouldn't worry about too much? Sure if it is only one person working on a project then there isn't too much to worry about. But what if this approach would be applied in a bigger project?

Thanks!

Comment: I worked on a project like this, personally I wouldn't recommend it, it gets really messy with more variables and even worse when you need to instantiate objects dynamically.

Comment: That's interesting because this approach is metioned in talks about SO. For example here: https://youtu.be/raQ3iHhE_Kk?t=926

My team and I are thinking about using this to a certain degree. Some systems in our game have data that needs to be shared with UI/other systems and we tried to think of a way to make the data protected.

Comment: Yep! that's exactly the video that inspired us to give it a go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be a bit controversial, but so is using `ScriptableObject` for this in the first place ^^

Unfortunately Unity still doesn't really support serializing of `interface` type fields. But in this case there is only two different access levels - read and write.

So you could do something like

```
// Just going generic here as latest Unity versions finally support it
// and you have way less re-implementation of the same functionality 
public abstract class ReadonlyValueSO<T> : ScriptableObject
{
    [SerializeField]
    [ReadOnly]
    protected T _value;

    public T Value
    {
        get => _value;
    }
}

public abstract class WriteableValueSO<T> : ReadonlyValueSO<T>
{
    public void Set(T value)
    {
        _value = value;
    }
}

// Some constants could even be ReadonlyValueSO if you never want to write over them anyway 
[CreateAssetMenu]
public class HealthSO : WriteableValueSO<float>
{
}
```

This way in your setter component you would use the writeable type and do e.g.

```
public class SomeSetter : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] WriteableValueSO<float> health;

    private void Update()
    {
        health.Set(health.Value + .1f * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

while in the consumers you only give it the readable

```
public class Consumer : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] ReadonlyValueSO<float> health;

    private void Update()
    {
        Debug.Log(health.Value);
    }
}
```

This way you have full control over who can read and who can write.

---

Another huge advantage: This way you also don't have to poll check values how I did above. You can rather simply add an even to be invoked whenever the value is set:

```
public abstract class ReadonlyValueSO<T> : ScriptableObject
{
    [SerializeField]
    protected T _value;

    public T Value
    {
        get => _value;
    }

    public abstract event Action<T> ValueChanged;
}

public abstract class WriteableValueSO<T> : ReadonlyValueSO<T>
{
    public void Set(T value)
    {
        _value = value;
        ValueChanged?.Invoke(_value);
    }

    public override event Action<T> ValueChanged;
}
```

now your consumer could rather look like e.g.

```
public class Consumer : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] ReadonlyValueSO<float> health;

    private void Awake()
    {
        // subscribe to event
        health.ValueChanged -= OnHealthChanged;
        health.ValueChanged += OnHealthChanged;

        // invoke now once with the current value
        OnHealthChanged(health.Value);
    }

    private void OnDestroy()
    {
        // IMPORTANT: Unsubscribe!
        health.ValueChanged -= OnHealthChanged;
    }

    // Always and only called whenever something sets the value
    private void OnHealthChanged(float newHealth)
    {
        Debug.Log(newHealth);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think your answer I as close to what I want to achieve as possible.
Thanks :)

My only issue with this would be that you could still use the type `WriteableValueSO` in the consumer and cheat your way out of this.

Comment: @t_Gmek as soon as you have access to the source code there is **always** ways (reflection as last resort) to access and manipulate any field or property. There is no real way to enforce what type you use either, no ;)